# Tensorflow VGG19 Error: ValueError: Shapes (None, 128, 128, 10) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I'm trying to use VGG-19 model as a semantic segmentation model i.e. pixel-wise classification. I have the following dataset ready:

```
x_trn.shape, y_trn.shape, x_val.shape, y_val.shape
((3883, 128, 128, 3),
 (3883, 128, 128, 10),
 (1237, 128, 128, 3),
 (1237, 128, 128, 10))
```

I have 3 Channels of Input Image, output has 10 possible classes, for each class the value can be `0 or 1`. It's one-hot encoded already

I'm using the following model architecture:

```
model = VGG19(include_top=False,
    weights=None,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(128,128,3)))

headModel = model.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(headModel)

combined_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=headModel)

combined_model.compile(Adam(0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Model Summary:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong here, but this gives shape mismatch error.

```
combined_model.fit(x=x_trn,
    y=y_trn,
    batch_size=10,
    epochs=10,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
    shuffle=True)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4687 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 128, 128, 10) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptual error in the code. Pixel-wise classification would require the output size to match input size i.e output layer should be `128x128x10`. Using `Conv2DTranspose` we can upsample back to `128x128`

I did few changes like these:

```
model = VGG19(include_top=False,
    weights=None,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(128,128,3)))

headModel = model.output
headModel = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.2)(headModel)

headModel = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)

headModel = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.7)(headModel)

headModel = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.8)(headModel)

headModel = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(headModel)
headModel = Conv2D(10, (1,1), activation = 'softmax')(headModel)
combined_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=headModel)
```